# CSS evento em um elemento aplicar em outro

Tags: html, css, animação

É possível com CSS fazer o seguinte código

```
.grupo-input input:hover .grupo-input span{
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Onde no HTML se encontra desta forma:

```
<label class="grupo-input">
    <span>Nome</span>
    <input type="text" name="filtro_nome">
</label>
```

Comment: Não[.](http://http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145951/70)

Comment: O CSS tem seletores de elementos dispostos sequencialmente, mas eles valem sempre para o último, e não afetam o anterior (o input não tem como afetar o que vem antes dele). Seria legal se você expusesse o problema ou efeito final que quer fazer, a melhor solução nem sempre o caminho que você imagina. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e explicar como é o efeito que quer fazer, e talvez a gente possa pensar numa estrutura melhor para chegar no resultado.

Comment: Nosso amigo respondeu certinho ali no post, era exatamente aquilo. Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Mesmo assim, é sempre bom a pergunta ficar o mais clara possível, para que ajude outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. Lembrando que quanto mais detalhada a pergunta, mais chance de ter uma variedade de respostas com propostas interessantes (nem sempre se tem a sorte de alguém experiente como o @Sergio postar uma resposta que coincide com o que você precisa). Para as próximas, tem umas dicas legais aqui: [Ask]. E que bom que essa já deu certo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quase :)

Existe um [seletor de CSS para elementos adjacentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), o `+`, mas ele só funciona para elementos que estão *a seguir*. E não como no teu caso que está *antes*.

Nota ainda que [o elemento `span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) é um elemento `inline` por defenição, para o poderes posicionar na vertical precisas de `display: block;` por exemplo.

Mas se o HTML puder ser trocado de ordem, então já dá:

```css
label {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grupo-input span {
    transition: margin-top .5s;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.grupo-input input:hover + span {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<label class="grupo-input">
    <input type="text" name="filtro_nome">
    <span>Nome</span>
</label>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g06s90jk/

Se quiseres podias ter ambos o `hover` e o `focus` para não ficar mais calmo: https://jsfiddle.net/g06s90jk/1/

Comment: Caramba cara, perfeito. Vou dar um olhada mais a fundo nesse caso de elementos adjacentes, muito obrigado!

Comment: @PedroSoares se vc mudar para absolute o span com o código do Sergio, vai ficar parecendo um placeholder, e quando puser o mouse em cima ele "sai"

Comment: Antes de me responderem fiz exatamente isso porém usando css com jquery, teria como fazer usando :Focus do CSS? Com certeza teria q ter uma piadinha de jquery para quando o campo não estiver em branco

Comment: @PedroSoares com `:focus` nativo seria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/g06s90jk/2/ é só mudar `:hover` para `:focus`

Comment: Ficou bacana cara.

Comment: Same example above but making the label pass behind
[https://jsfiddle.net/slexbr/5rL46vqh](https://jsfiddle.net/slexbr/5rL46vqh)